# Scala, advanced generic extending

Tags: generics, scala, extending

I'm trying to rewrite https://gist.github.com/319827 to Scala. But I can't compile it. What is the correct syntax?

Error I'm allways getting:

> class type required but java.util.Comparator[_ >:
>   java.lang.Comparable[java.lang.Object]] found

source:

```
package v6ak.util

import java.util.Comparator

object NaturalComparator extends Comparator[_ >: Comparable[Object]]{

    override def compare(o1:Comparable[Object], o2:Comparable[Object]) = {
        if( o1==null || o2==null ){
            throw new NullPointerException("Comparing null values is not supported!");
        }
        o1.compareTo(o2);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've returned to the problem with more experience and [solved it](https://gist.github.com/319827#file_natural_comparator.scala), although I think that is can be better.

```
package v6ak.util

import java.util.Comparator

object NaturalComparator extends Comparator[Comparable[Any]]{

    def apply[T]() = asInstanceOf[Comparator[T]]

    override def compare(o1:Comparable[Any], o2:Comparable[Any]) = {
        if( o1 == null || o2 == null ){
            throw new NullPointerException("Comparing null values is not supported!")
        }
        o1 compareTo o2
    }

}
```

Comment: you are right, the apply method does not enforce anything like <T extends Comparable<?>>. But this could be changed.

Answer (score 20):

`A extends B` is written `A<:B` in scala not `A>:B`

by the way, scala type system is powerful enough to avoid use of Object (AnyRef in scala) in your code

```
package v6ak.util

import java.util.Comparator

class NaturalComparator[T <: Comparable[T]] extends Comparator[T] {
  override def compare(o1: T, o2: T) = {
    if (o1 == null || o2 == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("Comparing null values is not supported!");
    }
    o1.compareTo(o2);
  }
}

object StringComparator extends NaturalComparator[String]

object Examples {
  StringComparator.compare("a", "b")
  StringComparator.compare(2, "b") // error
}
```

Comment: Well, it is not exactly the code I want. I really hate specialization (like specialization in ObjectPascal).

Comment: You can write less specialized code but you will loose type safety at compile time. Do you really want to be allowed to write code to compare `Date` with `File` that will fail only at runtime?

Comment: Hmm, but it is not the case of the original Java code. I think that I can write something similar to Java code in Scala, but it is not very nice.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you made some mess with that java version. Notice that you create an instance of Comparator< Comparable< Object>> and you assign it to value with wildcard - what for ? You won't assign anything else to that variable. Not talking that your getInstance also defines wildecards, while it returns everything the same Comparator< Comparable< Object>>

So:

```
object NaturalComparator extends Comparator[Comparable[Object]]{
    override def compare(o1:Comparable[Object], o2:Comparable[Object]) = {
        if(o1 == null || o2 == null){
            throw new NullPointerException("Comparing null values is not supported!");
        }
        o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a way that allows to have a single instance and use it for various types. It is de facto compatible, but Java has no power to explain it without @SuppressWarning. I don't think it is a mess.
Your code is not the code I want. Following code does not work: https://gist.github.com/d2d24794f61b5afb7d57